# android videoView.pause() doesnt work while .canPause() returns true

Tags: android, android-videoview

My android application can show streaming video. I have come across very strange behaviour of videoView. VideoView's playback can be started/paused via button, code is:

```
        playPause.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                boolean isPlaying = isChecked;
                if (isPlaying)
                {
                    videoView.pause();
                }
                else
                {
                    videoView.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

I call videoView.pause() to stop playing and videoView.start() to begin/continue playing. I tested this code on 3 devices:

1) Nexus 7, Android 4.2: play works fine, pause works fine, videoView.canPause() returns true.

2) Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.1: play works fine, pause doesn't stop the video, canPause() returns true.

3) LG P-350, Android 2.2 - play works fine, pause doesn't work, .canPause() returns false.

So, I can understand why it cant be paused on P-350 - because canPause is false. But what's going on with Galaxy S3 (or android 4.1 - I dont know what is the reason of such behaviour)?
This is just mess... how to make this working on all devices not only on some of them?

P.S. If I call .suspend()/.resume(), video is being buffered even if we stay at the same position, so this is not an option.

Comment: Have you solved this problem somehow?